# Phoenix Ecto.NoResultsError not automatically setting 404 status

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following controller action:

```
def edit(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  memo = Repo.get_by!(Memo, id: id, user_id: current_user(conn).id)
  changeset = Memo.changeset(memo)
  render(conn, "edit.html", memo: memo, changeset: changeset)
end
```

With the following test:

```
test "404s for editing when chosen resource does not belong to current user", %{conn: conn} do
  user = Repo.insert! %User{}
  memo = Repo.insert! %Memo{user: user}
  other_user = Repo.insert! %User{}
  assert_error_sent 404, fn ->
    conn
    |> with_current_user(other_user)
    |> get(memo_path(conn, :edit, memo))
  end
end
```

Where the `current_user/1` function in the controller finds the current user from the session and the `with_current_user/2` test helper function sets the current user for the test request.

When I run this test I successfully get an `Ecto.NoResultsError` as I would expect but the status code is `200` instead of `404`. I expect that Phoenix should be setting the `404` status automatically but it appears that is not happening. If I change the expectation to `assert_error_sent 200` the test passes, but that is not the behavior I want.

How can I make sure that the status is `404`?

Comment: The error status resolving is based on the `Plug.Exception` protocol. Do you have implementation for it for the ecto error? The default implementation is included in the `phoenix_ecto` package.

Comment: Yes, I have `{:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"}` as a dependency and I have a similar test passing where I do `Repo.get!(Memo, id)` in the `show` action for the `MemoController`.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @SimonH, no because an error is being raised. I could rescue it and set a 404, but I expect the `Ecto.NoResultsError` implementation of the `Plug.Exception` protocol to do it automatically (since that is what it is documented to do).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/controllers#section-setting-the-http-status, I would try

```
    conn
    |> put_status(404)
    |> render("edit.html", memo: memo, changeset: changeset)
```